# qrserver Error received while searching tcp/localhost:13050. Error: [3] All partitions are down

Tags: sharepoint, fastsearch

I am getting this Warning messages in logs on my Admin Server on Fast Search Farm: 
Repeating warnings under qrServer logs are:

- WARNING    qrserver Error received while searching
  tcp/localhost:13050. Error: [3] All partitions are down
- WARNING      qrserver Error received while searching
  tcp/localhost:13050. Error:    [8] Lost connection to sub-node
- WARNING    qrserver Error received while searching
  tcp/localhost:13050. Error: [12] 12'Wildcardexpansion error: number
  of terms will reach hardWildcardCutoff limit'

Rest Logs looks clear to me! Has anyone faced and solved this problem?

Comment: Can anyone please help?

Comment: Can Any One please help?